# Making an AcceptButton border invisible

Tags: c#, winforms, acceptbutton

I am working on a project that is using a Victorian look and feel:
[image]

The problem that I'm having is with the AcceptButton (or OK or default acceptance) button. Obviously, I can make the button transparent and I can set the borders to 0 width. The problem is that when this particular button (notice how the Cancel button doesn't have this problem) is marked as the AcceptButton it automatically draws a border around it.

Is there a property that I can set that will override this?

Thanks!

Comment: When in designer that is indicating the accept button.  If you run the app you should not see this unless that button, even the cancel, has focus. Unless you have tab stop set to false.

Comment: What you see is not a button border but  the focus indiactor. Do you really want to hide the focus from the user? Bad ui design, imo. You stil can do it by simple owner-drawing the button.

Comment: I'm seeing the border even in the app when i call this dialog box.I've disabled the mouse over and mouse down highlighting, too. Yes, technically, it's not good UI design, but this is a game and, traditionally, you get a bit more latitude in game UI.

Comment: You did choose FlatStyle.Flat, right? I only see it if the focus is on the button; by owner-drawing it the focuis rectangle is gone, unless I draw it.. You are of course quite right wrt games, but I still hate it if I don't see the focus. But using a color for this is fine as well..

Comment: Yes, I've chosen FlatStyle.Flat. The border appears when I set as the AcceptButton in the form itself.

Answer (score 3):

Subclass the Button and overide the `ShowFocusCues` property so that it returns False:

```
public class MyButton : Button
{

    protected override bool ShowFocusCues
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you've got the right idea but I need help in implementation. My button is called OKButton. And the form is SetScenarioSpeed. In what file would I insert this subclass?

Comment: `OKButton` should extend `MyButton`. This way you'll have reusable classes. Of cours `MyButton` should be named better :)

Comment: Why I can't see overridable property `ShowFocusCues` ?

Comment: It's `protected`  - maybe that's the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Got it. Here's the solution:

```
OKButton.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255); //transparent
```

Comment: You also need to set the `Width = 0` !

Comment: Accept your answer